# Converting NSDictionary to XML

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml, nsdictionary

I need to convert a dictionary to XML format for using with SOAP webservice in objective C .

```
Let the dictionary be {
    password = testpassword;
    username = testusername;
}
 and the converted result i need is : 

<password>testpassword</password>
<username>testusername</username>

i need a specific function to get output like this format for dynamic dictioanry .

many libraries are available but i dont get output like this .

thanks in advance ..
```

Comment: Do u need it as a file? A string? Do you have a schema? Two elements doesn't make XML.

Answer (score 3):

Please use below code for converting NSDictionary to XML.

```
+(NSString*)ConvertDictionarytoXML:(NSDictionary*)dictionary withStartElement:(NSString*)startele
{
    NSMutableString *xml = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@""];
    NSArray *arr = [dictionary allKeys];
    [xml appendString:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"];
    [xml appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<%@>",startele]];
    for(int i=0;i<[arr count];i++)
    {
        id nodeValue = [dictionary objectForKey:[arr objectAtIndex:i]];
        if([nodeValue isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]] )
        {
            if([nodeValue count]>0){
                for(int j=0;j<[nodeValue count];j++)
                {
                    id value = [nodeValue objectAtIndex:j];
                    if([ value isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
                    {       
                        [xml appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<%@>",[arr objectAtIndex:i]]];
                        [xml appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[value objectForKey:@"text"]]];
                        [xml appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"</%@>",[arr objectAtIndex:i]]];
                    }

                }
            }
        }
        else if([nodeValue isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
        {
            [xml appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<%@>",[arr objectAtIndex:i]]];
            if([[nodeValue objectForKey:@"Id"] isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
                [xml appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[nodeValue objectForKey:@"Id"]]]; 
            else
                [xml appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[nodeValue objectForKey:@"Id"] objectForKey:@"text"]]]; 
            [xml appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"</%@>",[arr objectAtIndex:i]]];
        }

        else
        {
            if([nodeValue length]>0){
                [xml appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<%@>",[arr objectAtIndex:i]]];
                [xml appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dictionary objectForKey:[arr objectAtIndex:i]]]]; 
                [xml appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"</%@>",[arr objectAtIndex:i]]];
            }
        }
    }

    [xml appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"</%@>",startele]];
    NSString *finalxml=[xml stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&" withString:@"&amp;"];
//  NSLog(@"%@",xml);
    return finalxml;
}
```

Comment: awesome. I corrected it a little and it woks fine. (see below)

Comment: Hmm.  Certainly has a problem handling nested dictionaries.

Comment: what is startele parameter

Answer (score 1):

Try this third-party 
https://github.com/nicklockwood/XMLDictionary.  It should work